# Estaba usando los pesos full_yolo_backend.h5¿Saben dónde puedo encontrar los pesos de backend que faltan?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, yolo

Estaba utilizando los pesos `full_yolo_backend.h5`. Sin embargo, las versiones actuales de Keras y TensorFlow, con las que se ejecutan estos pesos, ya no son compatibles con las nuevas versiones de estas bibliotecas. Esto ha provocado que el código que tenía anteriormente haya dejado de funcionar. Me gustaría saber si existen otros pesos de backend similares a `full_yolo_backend.h5` que sean compatibles con las versiones más recientes de Keras y TensorFlow, y dónde podría encontrarlos.

He explorado diversas alternativas, sin embargo, no he logrado encontrar una que funcione adecuadamente. Mi esperanza es que el código destinado a entrenar un modelo de reconocimiento de objetos opere de manera correcta.